# Q&A Getting separate instances of ViewModel across different fragments

Tags: android, viewmodel, android-livedata

I have two fragments. One fragment (InterfaceFragment) displays a spinner, which displays a list of strings (groupNames). I have this linked up to MutableLiveData<List> in my ViewModel. This sets the value of the MutableLiveData from a Room database. This all works and displays great.

Simplifying slightly, this main fragment can navigate to another fragment (EditGroupFragment) which can add or remove these groupNames from the database. Now of course I would like that when I navigate back it would automatically update the spinner's contents, however it doesn't. I am using the same viewmodel in both fragments, however I believe they are using two different instances of the viewmodel, so when the viewmodel in EditGroupFragment changes the value, this calls the onChanged() listener of the observers since I am re-installing them, however the value returned is outdated.

When the InterfaceFragment's onCreateView() is called, it re-initialises the viewmodel, and the spinner items are updated with the current correct items.
A simple solution is manually re-initialising the desired values in the viewmodel in the InterfaceFragment's onResume() method, however I feel this isn't the 'correct' solution, there is clearly something going wrong.

I believe I would need a way that changing the MutableLiveData value in EditGroupFragment causes the observers I set up in InterfaceFragment to call onChanged() and update the UI.

Different instances of the viewmodel:

```
/*
I/EditDictGroupFrag: dictViewModel = com.example.mydictionaryapp.dictionary.DictionaryInterfaceViewModel@8326975
DictInterface: dictViewModel = com.example.mydictionaryapp.dictionary.DictionaryInterfaceViewModel@80e8488


//I set the value in EditGroupFragment
I/onGetAllDictGroups: allDictGroups.value set to : [Test Group]

//I check what the value is in my InterfaceFragment
DictInterface : dictViewModel.allDictGroups.value = [Test Group 1, Test Group 2]
*/
```

Okay time for some code.

This is how I'm getting the viewmodel in each Fragment. (I don't wanna post all the other irrelevant code)

```
class DictionaryInterfaceFragment: Fragment() {
    private lateinit var dictViewModel: DictionaryInterfaceViewModel
        override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater,
            container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
        ): View? {
            dictViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(DictionaryInterfaceViewModel::class.java)
            dictViewModel.dictGroupNames.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
                    allDictGroups -> // set spinner items
                }    
            }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

So while writing out the question I stumbled upon a solution. By passing the activity into the ViewModelProvider both fragments can gain access to the same viewmodel, rather than the provider supplying  different instances to each fragment.

eg.

```
dictViewModel = ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(DictionaryInterfaceViewModel::class.java)
```

Please feel free to contribute anything else to the discussion, and I hope this helps someone.